# how to convert name=value pairs to Json

Tags: java, jackson

I need to call third party API and consume the response as JSON object, but they return name=value pair format even though they claim that's JSON format:

```
{body={user={first_name="foo",last_name="bar"}}
```

is there any library that can convert the above string to a real JSON ?

Comment: I believe you would have to pre-process that, e.g. replace `=` with `:` for this to work

Comment: It looks like you need to put " around keys and change = to :. You can do that with a couple regexs. You can run it through http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace = with : but there's something you have to be careful about. What if one of your JSON values contains a '='? Say:

```
{a="some=else"}.
```

Here is my solution:

```
static String formatJson(String x)
{
    if (x == null) return "";

    //quote keeps track of whether we are between quotes
    char quote = 0;
    char[] chars = x.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i)
    {
        char c = chars[i];
        if (quote != 0)//if we are in a quote section...
        {
            //if we get the same character as the original quote, 
            //then we are exiting the quote section
            if (c == quote)
            {
                quote = 0;
            }
            //let's not proceed evaluating anything in a quote section
            continue;
        }
        switch (c)
        {
            case '"':
            case '\'':
                quote = c;//we are getting into a quote section, marked by c
                break;
            case '=':
                chars[i] = ':';//let's replace = with :
                break;

        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(chars);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String x = "{body={user={first_name=\"f='something=else'=0\",last_name=\"bar\"}}";

    System.out.println(formatJson(x));
    //prints {body:{user:{first_name:"f='something=else'=0",last_name:"bar"}}
}
```